# ASP.NET Api error when adding user to role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.1 application and I'm trying to add a user to roles manually.

I'm not using Role Manager as the database I'm using is also accessed by a traditional ASP.NET MVC Application.

I have the following code to update a user:

```
public async Task<bool> Update(UserFormViewModel model)
{
    var user = await GetUserById(model.Id);
    _context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Id).IsModified = false;

    _context.Entry(user).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);

    user.AspNetUserRoles.Clear();
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    foreach (var role in model.Roles)
    {
        var aspnetuserrole = await _context.AspNetUserRoles.Where(x => x.RoleId == role).Include(x=>x.Role).Include(x=>x.User).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        user.AspNetUserRoles.Add(aspnetuserrole);
    }

    try
    {
        var result = await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This code is failing with the error:

> "The property 'UserId' on entity type 'AspNetUserRole' is part of a
>   key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified.

These are my models:

This is my ViewModel which is what gets submitted:

```
public class UserFormViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string[] Roles { get; set; }    
}
```

This is my App User model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles { get; set; }

}


public class AspNetUserRole
{        
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser User {get; set;}

    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    public AspNetRole Role {get; set;} 

}

public class AspNetRole
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256)]
    [Required]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUserRole> AspNetUserRoles {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var role in model.Roles)
    {
        var aspnetuserrole = new AspNetUserRoles()
           {
              UserId = model.Id,
              RoleId = role.Id
           };
        _context.AspNetUserRoles.Add(aspnetuserrole);
    }
```